# Web parts in horizontal orientation using CSS

Tags: web-part, web

I am looking to put web parts in horizontal orientation on the dispform.aspx page using the CEWP. Can this be done using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Example for dispform.aspx:

## ms-SPZone {

width:1200px;
}

## MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 {

float: left;
width:400px;
}

## MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4 {

float: right;
width;400px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}